# RuntimeException: An error occurred when executing the "cache:clear --no-warmup" command while update Symfony 2.4.1

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php

While I updating Symfony 2.4.1 via `composer` with command:

```
php composer.phar update
```

I get an error `RuntimeException: An error occurred when executing the "cache:clear --no-warmup" command.`

Comment: Many things can cause that error. Post the complete error you get

Comment: `RuntimeException: An error occurred when executing the "cache:clear --no-warmup" command.` is a complete error message, and I solved this with `"doctrine/orm": "~2.2.3",` in `composer.json`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is solution: you need to replace in `composer.json` file requirement:

```
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2,>=2.2.3",
```

with next requriment:

```
"doctrine/orm": "~2.2.3",
```

And run update again:

```
php composer.phar update
```

It's because composer try to download and install new `Doctrine` BETA version.

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue just by setting up the `timezone` variable in `php.ini` as below:

```
date.timezone = America/New_York
```

You can find a list of supported timezones at php official website:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try sudo composer update when updating your package.